# How to pass large response data from Java rest web service to the client?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am working on creating a Java Rest web service which provides a large report in JSON format. This can be as large as couple of millions rows. What is the best way to implement web service which will efficiently send this large data as a response to a client. As I can not convert record set to JSON in memory as it will create load on GC.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context :)

If you are serving the data as JSON (and presume you are by "jersey" tag), I suggest sending your object (rows of report) wrapped into structure implementing paging functionality.

```
{
    "current-page" : (num),
    "max-pages" : (numOfAllPages),
    "rows" : [{
       {(row1)},    {(row2)},   {(row...n)},
   }]
}
```

and your REST handler accepts QueryString parameter like: ?page=(num)

Unless, you need to send all rows at once.. If you do -- I would suggest writing directly to the response stream, setting correct response headers for user to trigger "download" operation.

Comment: Also make sure gzip is enabled on the server

Comment: there is handful of headers we can use -- again, depends on how one is going to address the problem.
in scenario of downloading big packages are, it's useful to use:
- content-transfer : gzip,deflate (read pros and cons of that solution!!)
- content-transfer : chunked
- accept-ranges : bytes

Answer (score 1):

There are few solutions
First is Paginate as Miron pointed out.

Second Chunky output
you send it using the [ChunkyOutput](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output) class.  In this your client also need to consume as [ChunkyInput](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10285)

```
@Path("/chunkyresource")
public class ResourceSentAsChunks {
    @GET
    public ChunkedOutput<String> chunkedGet() {
        System.out.println("ResourceSentAsChunks.chunkedGet()");
        final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(String.class);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                        output.write(i + " ");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
        return output;
    }
```

Third use compression if you can send your response as attachment or if you have your own client application . This technique quite widely used in case of images.